# Logarithmic Paper

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function, physics

I have a question related to logarithmic paper. Does the midpoint shows $0.5\times(10^{-1})$, or less than that because of increase of logarithmic also?

I am curious about the increase of intervals between lines actually.

[image]

Comment: Finally a question where the image is actually an important part of the question. :)

Comment: Thank you. I think the result is 0.11220184543. I realized it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the geometric mean between $10^{-1} = 0.1$ and $2 \times 10^{-1} = 0.2$: $\sqrt{0.1 \times 0.2} \approx 0.141421356237$.